# How from Forum model refer forumPosts?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In laravel 7 app I app/Forum.php model with method:

```
public function forumThreads()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ForumThread', 'forum_id', 'id');
}
```

app/ForumThread.php has field forum_id and:
public function forum()
{
return $this->belongsTo('App\Forum', 'id');
}

```
public function forumPosts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ForumPost');
}
```

and in app/ForumPost.php there are field forum_thread_id and:

```
public function forumThread()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\ForumThread'/*, 'user_id'*/);
}
```

can I in app/Forum.php make method referring post:

```
public function forumPosts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ForumPost');
}
```

and if yes, how?

Thanks!

Comment: check "has many through" relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though your eloquent looks confusing, but i will say guess what might need is using the "has many through" and "has one through" relationship.

Comment: Strange, that here  https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent these methods are not described. Please give a link where they are described

Comment: @mstdmstd in the "relationships" docs for Eloquent, as its a "relationship" ... there is a search bar at the top of the documentation pages btw